# Hackerrank Mini-Max Sum - Doesn't pass test case

Tags: javascript

I am working on Hackerrank challenge [Mini-Max Sum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem):

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
> ```
>
> The minimum sum is `1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16` and the maximum sum is `3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 24`.
>
> The function prints
>
> ```
> 16 24
> ```

I submitted the below code, but it doesn't pass one sample test case. Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let set = [...new Set(arr)];
    const MIN = set.filter((num) => num !== Math.max(...set)).reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);
    const MAX = set.filter((num) => num !== Math.min(...set)).reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);
    console.log(MIN + ' ' + MAX);
}
```

The error is a "Runtime Error"

Comment: I'll just point out that putting each statement/ function result on a single line, rather than chaining them (as it is done in trincot's answer), will help you find the exact line causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- A problem will occur when all 5 input values are equal. In that case the `filter` call will return an empty array, on which `reduce` is called. As `reduce` is called without the "initial value" argument, a run-time error will occur.
- There is no indication in the challenge that duplicate values should only be accounted for once in the sum. So if the input *does* contain duplicate values, this will not always produce correct results.

Not a problem, but:

- Calculating the min/max in *each* iteration of the `filter` callback is not efficient -- it will be the same result every time, so better calculate this only once.

Here is a working solution that takes the above points into consideration:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    const min = sum - Math.max(...arr);
    const max = sum - Math.min(...arr);
    console.log(`${min} ${max}`);
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can safely `.reduce()` _without_ the initial value `0` here.

Comment: I found another solution but this look great. thx for help

Comment: If you found another solution, please post it as an answer in support of this site.

Answer (score 1):

@Trincot already explained the error in all details. Nothing to be added there.

Here is yet another way of doing it by avoiding redundant calculations:

```
function mms(arr) { 
  const [a,...ar]=arr;
  let [min,max,sum]=[a,a,a];
  ar.forEach(c=>{
    if(c<min) min=c
    else if (c>max) max=c
    sum+=c
  });
  return `${sum-max} ${sum-min}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mx = max(arr)
mi = min(arr)
i = 0
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    a = sum(arr) - mx
    b = sum(arr) - mi
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you are used to Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayExcept {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ai = new ArrayList<>(5);
    ai.add(7);
    ai.add(69);
    ai.add(2);
    ai.add(221);
    ai.add(8974);
    int total =0;
    int max = ai.get(0);
    int min = ai.get(0);
    for(int n : ai){
        total+=n;
        if (n<min) {
            min = n;
        }
        if (n>max) {
            max = n;
        }
    }
    System.out.println((total - min) + " " + (total - max));

  }
}
```